# PyInstaller "Fatal Error: Failed to Execute Script main"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an executable I made through PyInstaller that's running every 10 minutes through Task Scheduler. It runs perfectly anywhere from a few hours to a couple days but eventually throws up a message box stating that it failed to execute my script.

When the failure occurs, Task Scheduler returns a 0x103 code. The script takes screenshots and uploads them to ShareFile. I don't understand why this would work hundreds of times in a row and then seemingly fail out of nowhere.

The command I used to create the .exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ScreenGrab.py --noconsole
```

Any help is appreciated and I'm happy to provide more info if I failed to add enough context to the question.

Comment: Almost impossible to say without seeing the code (or preferably a minimal example thereof that reproduces the problem), or some error logging.    Since you're uploading to an external service, it's possible you have occasional internet connectivity issues or other externalities that will cause it to fail on occasion, and you need to make your script more robust to that possibility.

Comment: A big issue in troubleshooting this has been that I can't reproduce the problem. On the scheduled task, I have it set to only run if there is internet connectivity. My script will also make several attempts to upload the picture if it fails initially.